# Create a vinyl graphics cutting software in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics

For those who don't know what a vinly cutting software is read it here - https://www.signwarehouse.com/blog/a-basic-guide-to-vinyl-signs-graphics/

I want to understand how can one create such applications, for e.g. if you want to have a print functionality in your software they you can use windows default printer to print it and if you are writing code in VB.NET you will find print menu option available in developer IDE which you can use.

My question is how can I use Cut functionality if I have Vinly Cutter with me

Comment: `those who don't know what a vinly cutting software is` won't be here helping. Apart that your question is too broad, therefore (probably) nobody will.

Answer (score 1):

All computer devices are dumb machines that accept commands from the computer and then execute those commands. You just need to find how to communicate with such device and what commands it understands. Because printers are so ubiquitous, each OS/language/UI framework comes with a library that exposes those commands as simple API for programmers to call, that also works for all printers. Case of a cutter might be different. It is definitely going to have some API, but that API might not be available to you. Or you might need to pay to use it. And I'm skeptical there is generic Cutting API, that works with any cutter, so you might need to have different library for each manufacturer.

So first thing to do is to go to device manufacturer's website and search for way to communicate with the device using code. If you won't find anything, then only next step is to write them an email and ask if there is a way to control the cutter through software. And it is quite possible they won't give you that information, because they want only theirs software to be able to use the device.

If it comes to that, you are basically screwed. There is third option of reverse-engineering the communication protocol. But that would be extremely hard even for experienced programmer. And if you have to ask this question, I'm sure it will be way over your abilities. And even if you succeed in reverse-engineering the API, there is still possibility of legal action from their side and if they change the API even slightly, you will get back to square one.